# AWS Lambda dynamic concurrency limit based on if other lambdas are running

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

The problem:

- Lambda A - Makes 1 requests to third party API
- Lambda B - Makes 10 requests to third party API

I want a limit of 15 requests to the third party API at once

Ideal scenario:

- If Lambda B is running, 5 Lambda A can run concurrently.
- If Lambda B is not running, 15 Lambda A can run concurrently.

From what I've read you can set the concurrency limit per function e.g. I could set the limit for Lambda B at 1, and the limit for lambda A at 5. A lot lower than the ideal scenario.

Is the ideal scenario possible with AWS lambdas?

Comment: How are these being invoked? Via an API Gateway?

Comment: Hi mokugo-devops, yep the api is via an api gateway. @mokugo-devops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using the API Gateway you can make use of [API Gateway Throttling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html) on the stage.

By adding throttling here you can limit the number of concurrent requests across all attached Lambda functions to that single deployment.

Comment: So for example I would say the account level rate limit would be 15. Then for lambda B I would set the  default method throttling to override the account-level request throttling limits to 5?

Comment: Yes, you could do this. Outside of this you would need to create your own throttling solution.